# Qualtrics text box not fillable

Tags: qualtrics

One of my users has created a survey with several text box questions. His settings on these questions are such that the box is an "essay text box" and there is no validation selected. Some of the respondents are not able to enter text into these text boxes when completing the survey. Others have no problem with it. Unfortunately, I don't have details about which browser and OS they are using. Could this be a browser compatibility issue? Is there anything else I should look at?
Thanks!

Comment: Add a Metainfo question to your survey.  Then you'll be able to see which browser and OS they are using.

Comment: You can also add the embedded data UserAgent and it will be available for all respondents, even ones who have already taken the survey.